# Xetex problems with division symbol

Tags: symbols, unicode

When using this symbol in a text ÷ XeLaTex says:

```
ERROR: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined

--- TeX said ---
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.218 two typographic operators, ÷
                                    and × (these ones are produced in the
--- HELP ---
```

It works with the aleph and alpha character, but this one seems to be missing. I have included `unicode-math`, any other additional package I should be including?
Besides, it does not like ² and the multiplication "x", either. The former is not in the `unicode-math` package, but the \times and \div symbol should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A XeLaTeX run on the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

two typographic operators, ÷ and ×

\end{document}
```

only shows a warning

```
Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.
```

You have an outdated TeX distribution, as the package has been issuing this warning since version 1.2b, released 2014/04/30.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Erase or comment out

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and it will work like a charm. `fontenc` and `inputenc` are not really needed in xelatex.

Comment: That's a well known truth that `inputenc` is not needed for `xelatex` ;-)

Comment: Well, including it wasn't producing any warning, and the error was not "I don't understand this symbol because you included an unneeded package" I am not too familiar with XeLaTex, either, I'm afraid... I just figured out it was the way to go with the Unicode file (produced by org-mode, BTW)